# Workflow ServiceHost Design - Resuming a workflow from client

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm getting to grips with WF4, and am currently experimenting with a proof of concept design for a simple Expenses Approval system. I want to use WorkflowService hosted in IIS to enable a web client to submit approvals. My current design is as follows (assume we're just passing in an expenseID and a isApproved boolean to the Receive activities):

[WF4 Expense Workflow http://i56.tinypic.com/esohno.jpg](http://i56.tinypic.com/esohno.jpg)

One aspect I'm unclear about is that, the client would need to know exactly which Receive activity to call next. To do that the client would need to know exactly where the workflow is at (by querying a datasource), switching on some sort of state flag, and calling the appropriate Receive activity. But in doing this surely I'd be bypassing the point of using a persisted workflow?

It could just be that my design is plain wrong, so I'd welcome any input or guidance on how best to acheive this task or improve the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this result, but you should provide API documentation with your service contract to attempt to make this behaviour clear to your clients. The WSDL of the service will not make this clear by itself.

With regard to the implementation, the only way to achieve this is outside WF. This is because you will get a content correlation error on loading the workflow when the client attempts to invoke a service method that it is not allowed to call according to the workflow flowchart rules.

The WF service host will not be able to load the persisted workflow instance and will therefore throw an error that you will need to catch in a WCF IErrorHandler. You will then need to determine what the scenario is and convert the exception into a service fault that can be understood by the client.

I wrote a blog post a while ago the provides an example of how this works - http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/11/09/Managing-content-correlation-failures.aspx.

Comment: Hmm, so would you say this example doesn't really lend itself to WF? Sounds like WF might be better suited to a single entry point into a given workflow?

Comment: I would actually say the opposite. WF is perfect for this, but you need to understand that WCF by itself does not present state transitions to a WCF client via the description of the service contract.

At the end of the day, if you are happy for clients to either read a well written API document that defines how to use the service that works like this, or have them hit their head against the business validation rules if they don't read the manual, then this will work well.

It kind of depends on what type of service design/developer experience is suitable.

Comment: I think the first step is to clearly define who your clients are. 

If it is the general public, then you may want to redesign your service contract so that the operations clearly define the process (you may already be happy with the status quo). 

Alternatively, if the set of clients is restricted, then that makes it much easier to adopt a service design like this.